# PLY import turns out in empty col fields with value Zero

Tags: import

[image: Col=zero]
File import in Blender with col values 0

[image: Col visible in cloudcompare]
Cloudcompare pointcloud with RGB colors

If i view the file in cloudcompare it has color info.
Imported in blender colors are gone and col fields show 0 0 0 1 where they should have values.

These imported pointclouds are exported out of webODM

Anyone any clue why?